# Can Npgsql dump/restore an entire database?

Tags: vb.net, npgsql, pg-dumpall

Is it possible to use Npgsql in a way that basically mimics [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) to a single output file without having to iterate through each table in the database?  Conversely, I'd also like to be able to take such output and use Npgsql to restore an entire database if possible.

I know that with more recent versions of [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) I can use the `BeginBinaryExport`, `BeginTextExport`, or `BeginRawBinaryCopy` methods to export from the database to STDOUT or to a file.  On the other side of the process, I can use the `BeginBinaryImport`, `BeginTextImport`, or `BeginRawBinaryCopy` methods to import from STDIN or an existing file.  However, from what I've been able to find so far, these methods use the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) SQL syntax, which (AFAIK) is limited to a single table at a time.

***Why am I asking this question?***  I currently have an old batch file that I use to export my production database to a file (using `pg_dumpall.exe`) before importing it back into my testing environment (using [`psql.exe` with the `<` operation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)).  This has been working pretty much flawlessly for quite a while now, but we've recently moved the server to an off-site hosted environment, which is causing a delay that prevents the batch file from completing successfully.  Because of the potential for other connectivity/timeout issues, I'm thinking of moving the batch file's functionality to a .NET application, but this part has got me a bit stumped.

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked for in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1397.

Long story short, Npgsql doesn't have any sort of support for dumping/restoring entire databases. Implementing that would be a pretty significant effort that would pretty much duplicate all the pg_dump logic, and the danger for subtle omissions and bugs would be considerable.

If you just need to dump data for some tables, then as you mentioned, the COPY API is pretty good for that. If, however, you need to also save the schema itself as well as other, non-table entities (sequence state, extensions...), then the only current option AFAIK is to execute pg_dump as an external process ([or use one of the other backup/restore options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Based on your answers here and in the Github issue thread, I'm assuming there are currently no intentions to *ever* implement such a feature.  I know I can use a `Process` object in my .NET application to launch the `pg_dump` executable (which I'll work on implementing to replace my batch file) and I understand the "dangers" of trying to implement the functionality in Npgsql. Even so, it would be nice to be able to have a method available for this purpose without having to resort to such tactics.  If you ever decide to do this, I'll be happy to help with testing.

Comment: Because of the risks involved in such a feature, the considerable amount of work and the few requests (this is only the 2nd time someone's asked for it), I don't think it makes sense to implement this. If more people ask for it that may change.